# How to test, that that certain form will NOT come up in Oracle Openscript

Tags: java, openscript

Oracle Openscript comes with the mechanism,  to verify/assert , that certain form will appear. If the condition is not met, then script fails.   E.g.

```
forms.listOfValues(40, "//forms:listOfValues").assertAttributes(
                "My test",
                forms.attributes(forms.attribute("title", "Find People",
                        TestOperator.StringExact), forms.attribute("name",
                        "FULL_NAME_LOV", TestOperator.StringExact)), 5);
```

The above test fails the script execution, if such form does not come up.

But the question is: how do I test exactly opposite: I want script to fail/ or to execute differently if the the given form will appear and  I want it to execute normally if the from will Not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several methods , such as

```
if (forms.listOfValues(40, "//forms:listOfValues").isVisible()){
    reportFailure("messag"); //just report a failure or
    fail("message"); // fail and stop execution 
    // or what ever you do .. 
}
```

Comment: I  found, that the solution does not work out of the box, because it generate the error, if the form is not available.

The solution, which I found is described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62629189/